# おか means 'pile' in [来年も仕事があるとは限らないから、ちゃんと貯金しておかなければいけない。] right?

Tags: meaning

Japanese version:

> 来年も仕事があるとは限らないから、**ちゃんと**貯金して**おか**なければいけない。

English version:

> There's no guarantee that there will be work next year so I need to make sure to save some money **while I can**.

1. Why are 'ちゃんと=seriously' and 'おか=pile' not mentioned in the English version?
2. Where is the 'while I can' in the Japanese version? Or is ちゃんと=while I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おか is not 'pile' here. It is a conjugation of the auxiliary verb おく.

A verb in te-form + おく means to do the verb in advance, or in preparation for something. So 貯金しておく means to save money in preparation for something, i.e. for the possibility that there will be no work next year. I think this is where the 'while I can' part of the English translation comes from.

I find ちゃんと rather a tricky word. I guess 'diligently' would work here. We can only guess why the translator omitted a translation of this word, but I don't think it really adds anything to the English translation.